# Calling a param of a model which belongs_to another

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a `ProgressBoard` model, controller and view. Each `has_many :progress_board_metrics` which `belongs_to` it.

I only have a `ProgressBoardMetric` model (no controller or view), it belongs to `progress_board`

In my `progress_board` view is displayed many unique `progress_board_metrics`

I want to call a param **metric_id** from `progress_board_metrics` model when I click on a button on a `metric` but I've hard times doing it.

My actual code trying to call this param is:

```
@progress_board.progress_board_metrics.metric_id
```

I tried some variations like `@progress_board.metric_id` or `#@progress_board_metrics.metric_id` but nothing made the trick.
I'm lost at this point

```
class ProgressBoardMetric < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :progress_board
  ...
  def metric_id
    if self.metric_type == "Change"
      self.change.id
    elsif self.metric_type == "Indicator"
      self.indicator.id
    elsif self.metric_type == "Outcome"
      self.outcome.id
    end
  end
  ...
end
```

Note: 'change', 'indicator' and 'outcome' are `metric_type`

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to select a singular value `id` on many records. You need to select an actual `progress_board_metric` to call `id` on.

For example:
`@progress_board.progress_board_metrics.first.metric_id` would select the first in the list. `@progress_board.progress_board_metrics.last.metric_id` would select the last in the list.

You could and probably will end up using an each do block to display the metric id in some way.

```
@progress_board.progress_board_metrics.each do |metric|
  metric.metric_id
end
```

Comment: Should I do this both in my controller and view file ?

Comment: If you want to display a value then probably a view file

Comment: I'm trying to display an attached image which is a param for my model